# M1 Max MBP: Magsafe works erratically

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, magsafe

I have a M1 Max MBP, macOS Sonoma 14.1.1. The MagSafe works erratically, that is, when I connect it to the laptop it might immediately show signs (light/sound) that the battery is charging, or it might take a few tries (nothing happens when I connect).

The connectors are clean, so I am not sure what is going on.

EDIT: the battery seems to be ok

[image: Battery status]

Comment: What happens if you wait a bit with it plugged (like 30s). I'm having this kind of behaviour sometimes but I just wait for a few seconds and it starts charging normally. If it doesn't work, you can just follow the steps here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203207 to diagnose an eventual issue.

Comment: It happens to me, so I hold it close then let it SNAP in

Comment: It seems to have an up and down -- if I turn it 180 degrees it works immediately, otherwise it does not, and it never seems to pass power